# BuddyPress activity on edit post for a CPT

Tags: plugins, wp-query, buddypress

I have a Custom Post Type `classified` I figured out how to record an activity in the BuddyPress activity stream whenever a new post of type `classified` is created.

What I am specifically looking to do is either modify the above code or start fresh so that whenever a **post of type `classified` is edited** a new activity is recorded.

Here is the inspiration for the original code if it helps

https://bp-tricks.com/snippets/adding-a-new-activity-stream-entry-when-a-user-changes-his-avatar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `save_post` hook. Try something like:

```
function jude_classified_activity_entry( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    $slug = 'classified';

    if ( $slug != $post->post_type )
        return;

    bp_activity_add( 
      // etc
    );

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'jude_classified_activity_entry', 15, 3 );
```

Comment: Is there a way to check if the post was updated and not created when this triggers ? The codex is not very clear on the params for this hook. Im guessing we can use `$update` somehow .. but not sure. I already have it setup for a new post using the `publish_post` hook.

Comment: You can just use save_post and check status to make sure it's not a draft.